# Redirect from old subdomain/domain to new domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

My website was on a subdomain, like this: mysite.primarydomain.com. The primarydomain.com DNS was managed by a third party who owns the primarydomain.com url.

My new website is now on on mysite.com. I had the third party add an a record that points mysite.primarydomain.com to my new website's IP address. How can I then redirect that mysite.primarydomain.com domain to mysite.com? Would that be via htaccess? Or via cpanel configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a cpanel configuration to do this pretty easily, probably something like this: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/SetupForwarding

But you can also add an htaccess file to the document root of the `mysite.primarydomain.com` site, that says:

```
Redirect 301 / http://mysite1.com/
```

or if the document root is shared, you'll need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\primarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Lin for your answer. It inspired me to find a very easy method in cpanel...

In the primarydomain.com, I created a subdomain for "mysite.primarydomain.com".

I then went to "Redirects". Since I added the "mysite." subdomain, it gave me the option to create a redirect using that subdomain. So I created a redirect for mysite.primarydomain.com to point to mysite.com.

I then was able to create a few other redirects to help keep some of their old links live, such as "mysite.primarydomain.com/about".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, a code only answer is not high quality.  It would be better to describe how this code works, explain why this approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.